# Why do the default Parameter Schemas need to be renamed when upgrading to 2013 SP1?

Tags: 2013

In the documentation for upgrading to SDL Tridion 2013 SP1, and specifically in the Upgrading the Content Manager Server -> Preparing for the Content Manager server upgrade section, there are instructions to rename the default TBB Parameter Schemas from "[name] Parameter Schema" to "[name]". So, taking the example from the documentation:

> [...] you would rename the item Default Finish Actions Parameter Schema to Default Finish Actions.

This is a simple enough task and easy to accomplish, but my question is *why* the schemas need to be renamed? What's going on under the hood that necessitates the change?

Thanks!

Comment: I've completed the upgrade to SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 and also updated the Default Building Blocks using Template Builder. However when I try to publish any DCP or Page I am getting the following error: Unexpected namespace URI: uuid:a13c5753-adfc-4e93-912f-ee3d93b6a828. Expecting: uuid:C695849C-4EFA-4F72-B8F2-68170C9F86C3. where "C695849C-4EFA-4F72-B8F2-68170C9F86C3" is the uuid of the new parameter schema and "a13c5753-adfc-4e93-912f-ee3d93b6a828" is the uuid of the old parameter schema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At some point - I think in the 2011 product line - some of the Parameters Schemas for the default templates were renamed. A recurring issue with the default templates is that the product can't tell where you have created them - which Publications, Folders, etc. So it is always up to the person doing the upgrade to manually update them by going to the Tools menu in Template Builder and choosing "Create Default Building Blocks".

When you do that, it will update all of the default templates found in the Folder you specified (or rather, the "Default Templates" sub-folder inside it). It matches these by names (since the TCM URIs are going to be different for everyone).

So if your templates have the old name, it won't be able to update it and would instead create  a new Schema - leaving you with a "duplicate" old version hanging around.

Anyway, if the Parameters Schemas of your default templates don't have "Parameters Schema" in their names you can ignore the step. Also, the worst that's going to happen if you missed this step is that you have some old Schemas in there which aren't in use anymore.

Comment: Excellent, this makes sense - thanks Peter!

Comment: I am upgrading from SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 to SDL Tridion 2013 SP1. If I missed this step, I can still rename the Parameter Schemas after upgrading to 2013 SP1 but before I update the Default Templates using Template Builder - right?

Comment: That's correct, @hzahid.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hunch here (call it educated guess), but I think the original Schemas might be overwritten and the rename is done to preserve the existing Schemas and create new Schemas next to it.

Since overwriting the Schema would result in invalid content (parameters in this case), the rename instructs the user to explicitly rename it so they *know* that a new Schema has been created.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure about that - Bart Koopman has a comment on the topic where he states that renaming the schemas may not be required when upgrading from 2013 GA to 2013 SP1, as the schemas have already been renamed in 2013 GA. If the goal was to avoid overwriting implementation-customized schemas, wouldn't it be required regardless of which version you were upgrading from?

Comment: It might be so... But maybe something changed in the Param Schema in SP1 ?

Comment: It's the opposite, Mihai- see my answer. Remember that the Schemas in question are only used by the templates which are updated - so you'd want to overwrite them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I logged a documentation defect about that instruction in the documentation yesterday, in line with the comment I placed there.

The thing which worries me most is the location of the step, it is mentioned right after the CM database upgrade, but before the CM core upgrade. At that time you should probably not be logging in your CMS and making any changes. So it should either be done as a pre step (before the entire upgrade) or as a post step (after the entire upgrade and before you run the Template Builder to upgrade your Default Templates).

The step about running the Template Builder to upgrade your Default Templates seems to be missing from the documentation all together. That is also what I mentioned in my defect description. I expect it to be addressed soon, so the confusion shouldn't be there anymore in a few days.

As to the reason why, I follow Peters answer, when you run the Template Builder to upgrade your Default Templates, it won't make new Parameter Schemas, but use the existing ones. As far as I know, there isn't any actual change in the Parameters Schemas since their original release.